# Find all the integers which are of form $\dfrac{b+c}{a}+\dfrac{c+a}{b}+\dfrac{a+b}{c}, a,b,c\in \mathbb{N}$, any two of $a,b,c$ are relatively prime.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, solution-verification

> I have a question which askes to find all the integers which can be
> expressed as
>
> $\displaystyle \tag*{} \dfrac{b+c}{a}+\dfrac{c+a}{b}+\dfrac{a+b}{c}$
>
> where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{N} $  and any two of $a,b,c$ are relatively
> prime.

My approach:

Since they told any two of $a,b,c$ are relatively prime, so:

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \begin{align} \text{gcd}(a,b) &= 1 \\ \text{gcd}(b,c) &= 1 \\ \text{gcd}(c,a) &= 1\end{align}$

We have:
$\displaystyle \tag*{} \dfrac{b+c}{a}+\dfrac{c+a}{b}+\dfrac{a+b}{c} = \dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{c}{a}+\dfrac{c}{b}+\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{a}{c}+\dfrac{b}{c}$

And we have to prove:
$\displaystyle \tag*{} \frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}+ \frac{c}{a} + \frac{a}{c}+ \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{b} \in \mathbb{N} $

We have the following that if $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$ and $m,n,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ then

$\displaystyle \tag*{} \frac{m}{n} + \frac{n}{m} = k$

has only $1$ positive solution, which is $m=n=1$

So, the only solution I found is $a=b=c=1$.

Is there anything I am missing? Any help would be appreciated, thank you. :)

Comment: Assuming $a=b$ is not consistent with the condition $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson They asked any two of $a,b,c$ has gcd as 1. No conditions on 3rd number. So I took gcd$(b,c)=$, so $a$ can be anything.

Comment: I think *any* here means *every*.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh, thank you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited my post, can you please check it now? Thank you.

Comment: $(a, b, c)=(1, 2, 3)$ gives 8 and I think this is unique solution.

Comment: @4444 FYI, using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Bb%2Bc%7D%7Ba%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Bc%2Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7Ba%2Bb%7D%7Bc%7D%24&p=1), I found the closely related [Diophantine equation $\frac{a+b}{c}+\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{a+c}{b} = n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1967149/602049), with this one only requiring $\gcd(a,b,c)=1$, so it allows two of the variables among $a$, $b$ and $c$ to not be coprime.

Comment: it doesnt say a b & c have to be distinct. if we let a b & c all equal 1 (as 1 & 1 are relative prime to each other) we have (1+1)/1 + (1+1)/1 + (1+1)/1 = 2+2+2 = 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)}{abc}\in \mathbb{N}$, therefore $abc|ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)$. Because $ab(a+b)$ and $ca(c+a)$ is a multiple of $a$, $a|bc(b+c)$ is true. $bc$ is coprime with $a$, thus $a|b+c$. Using the same ways, it can be proven that $$a|b+c \\ b|a+c \\ c|a+b$$ WLOG $a\geq b\geq c$. Therefore $b+c$ is $a$ or $2a$. If $a=b+c$, then $b|b+2c$ and $b|2c$. If $b=c$, then $(a,b,c)$ is $(2,1,1)$ and the value is 7. If $b=2c$, $(a,b,c)$ is $(3,2,1)$ and the value is 8. If $2a=b+c$, then $(a,b,c)$ is $(1,1,1)$ and the value is 6. Therefore, all integers possible are 6, 7 and 8.

Answer (score 3):

*NB: While I was typing up my proof, @user provided a similar proof, leaving mine essentially a duplicate. However, I'll leave it since I may have written it out in slightly greater detail.*

First, we may note that $c$ must divide $a+b$, etc. To see this, write the sum on common denominator
$$
\frac{b+c}a+\frac{a+c}b+\frac{a+b}c
=\frac{bc(b+c)+ac(a+c)+ab(a+b)}{abc}
$$
and note that, for $c$ to divide the numerator, after removing terms that are multiples of $c$, we are left with $c|ab(a+b)$, which forces $c|a+b$. Similarly, $a|b+c$ and $b|a+c$.

We may assume that $a\le b\le c$, where equality is only possible for the number 1. So let's first deal with the cases where equalities are an issue.

First, $a=b=c=1$ is a solution. Ie, $(a,b,c)=(1,1,1)$.

Next, if $a=b=1<c$, we need $c|a+b$, for which the only option is $c=2$. This is also a solution. Ie $(a,b,c)=(1,1,2)$.

So now we are left with the case $a<b<c$. Since $c|a+b$, but $a+b<2c$, we must have $c=a+b$. Next $b|a+c=2a+b$, so $b|2a$; however, $a<b$, so $2a=b$ since $2a$ is a multiple of $b$ but less than $2b$. This also forces $a=1$ since $a$ and $b=2a$ should be relatively prime. This makes $(a,b,c)=(1,2,3)$.