# Technique behind solving 4 = $\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{c}{a+b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, algebraic-number-theory

The question:

4 = $\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{c}{a+b}$

Where I have to find the minimum values for a, b and c and they have to be positive and whole?

I'm slightly confused by all the requests so it's a little tough to figure out the quirks. A step in the right direction would be great.

Comment: What are trying to minimize? Is it $a + b + c$?

Comment: Follow the following link:.     https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ami.ektf.hu/uploads/papers/finalpdf/AMI_43_from29to41.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiBo9blqfbeAhUHMo8KHcwnCz0QFjAAegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw0emp3ire4VvHNgzTt1_d9o

Comment: According to this [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227713/estimating-the-size-of-solutions-of-a-diophantine-equation/227722), the smallest positive solution is
$$\small\begin{align}
a &= 4373612677928697257861252602371390152816537558161613618621437993378423467772036;\\
b &= 36875131794129999827197811565225474825492979968971970996283137471637224634055579;\\ 
c &= 154476802108746166441951315019919837485664325669565431700026634898253202035277999;
\end{align}$$ This is definitely not a algebra-precalculus/contest problem.

Comment: Oh lol, so I've been bamboozled. Thanks for the answers though, it's interesting reading.

Comment: Previously discussed here at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402537/find-integer-in-the-form-fracabc-fracbca-fraccab