# 3 integer unknowns and 1 equation

Tags: cryptography

All numbers are integers and none equate to 0.

$$ 4=\frac{a}{b+c}+ \frac{b}{a+c} + \frac{c}{b+a} $$

My friend made this question, I tried to solve it for 2 hours and then he told me that I needed to use cryptology. I want to see how questions like these are solved. Answers: -1, 4, 11

Comment: I get $11, 9$, and $-5$.

Comment: "Use cryptology" is not a meaningful hint as far as I can tell.

Comment: Note that you need to add a requirement that they are not divisible by same number.

Comment: It's an interesting maths problem if the constraint $a,b,c \gt 0$ is added, which is the usual form of the question

Comment: See this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402537/find-integer-in-the-form-fracabc-fracbca-fraccab

Comment: I think by "crypto" your friend might have meant elliptic curves

Comment: As an aside, I once posted the equation on facebook using fruit, as a counter to all the tedious simultaneous equation puzzles that were appearing on social media at the time. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wa744g6K5HOIsiaI3TX3jOpv9y9pKoYX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks @ArthurVause

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find integer in the form: $\frac{a}{b+c} + \frac{b}{c+a} + \frac{c}{a+b}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402537/find-integer-in-the-form-fracabc-fracbca-fraccab)